# UIImage from url takes long time to load swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiimage

I have a `UITableView` with A lot of `UITableViewCell`, I use this code to load content and images to the `UITableCell` but it takes long time for the image to show for each `UITableViewCell`.

```
var loadOnce : [String] = []

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ProfileActivities", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ProfileActivitiesTableViewCell


    if !loadOnce.contains("\(indexPath.row)") {

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), {
            let LocationImage = self.postmap[indexPath.row]
            let LocationImageUrl = NSURL(string: LocationImage)
            let LocationImageData = NSData(contentsOfURL: LocationImageUrl!)

            let ProfileImage = self.postimg[indexPath.row]
            let ProfileImageUrl = NSURL(string: ProfileImage)
            let ProfileImageData = NSData(contentsOfURL: ProfileImageUrl!)

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                cell.locationImg.image = UIImage(data: LocationImageData!)
                cell.activitesProfileImg.image = UIImage(data: ProfileImageData!)
            });
        });
        loadOnce.append("\(indexPath.row)")

    }
    return cell
}
```

Putting the code in dispatch_async made scrolling smother but its still takes time to load images.

how to make it load images faster considering I have to many images something like Facebook or Instagram.

Thanks.

Comment: what's the size of the images you're loading? if you're just displaying thumbnails, make sure you download thumbnail versions of the images with the small resolution instead of high res images. But in the end, there's nothing you can do about a slow internet connection to the source of the images. It helps if you can cache them yourself on a CDN.

Comment: also your code isn't going to work like this, because you're not caching your images anywhere. So when scrolling back and forth, due to your loadOnce array, images won't be loaded a second time, but they are also not fetched from your cache (and dequeued cell will keep the image that was there previously which might be that of the wrong row).

Comment: use SDWebImage as SeanLintern88 said. it is perfect. am using it too

Comment: @dirkgroten why do i need to load image second time , sorry but i am new to swift i need to know why , also ill try SDWebImage catch n see results btw i am testing with only 1 image [link](http://www.bergfeldrecreation.com//catalog//3826//snap%20futs%20out%20com%2085.jpg)

Comment: @DavidSeek yes i will try it out :)

Comment: Of course you can use SDWebImage because it'll do a lot of the heavy lifting for you. But it's also good to first understand how tableViews work on iOS. Basically when a cell goes off the screen (user scrolling) it can be reused (with dequeueReusableCell...) for a different row. So you have to update the image to be the correct one. That's why you should save images you download to disk and associate them with the correct index in your model, not to a row in the table. If the image is not in cache, you start downloading and display a placeholder. When download finishes you refresh your view.

Comment: @dirkgroten Yes starting to understand now :) , i am only 2 weeks in swift lol, i added SDWebImage and its working much much better :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There will be issue because of Async call and ReUsability. Lets say your Image at IndexPath 1 is loading image but it is still taking time to download and meanwhile user scrolled down at some another index i.e. 15 and Internally the same cell of Index 1 is alloted to Index 15 and Image of cell 1 will be displayed in Cell 15 if you have not managed to handle previous calls for same instance of cell. Thats why its Better to use some caching library like [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage)(As @SeanLintern88 said) or [AFNetworking's UIImageView Category](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/tree/master/UIKit%2BAFNetworking)

[AlamoFire's UIImageView (For Swift)](https://github.com/Alamofire/AlamofireImage)

Event if you wanted to do this, then better is to go with subclassing, it will help you to manage the Calls and Its termination.

In your case the Loading of Image might be because of Size of actual image that you are loading from server. CDN kind of service provide some easy to implement techniques to serve different size of images as per the request. So even If User has uploaded 1200x1200 sized image but on list screen you can fetch its 120x120 sized image, This helps is faster loading as well as it will save Physical Memories.

Comment: "Image of cell 1 will be displayed in Cell 15" can you explain more about this please , What i though is each row as an index so if he scroll to index 15 it will show postimg[15] in cell 15 after it loads postimg[1]

Comment: As I said, you are using the same LocationImageData downloaded to create Image and assign it in UIImageView, so if Respons of some previous call comes to late then its data will be populated on the image even your current cell is not that one.

Either you should put a Check condition whether the downloaded data is for the current IndexPath or not.

Answer (score 2):

Use one of the following libraries to asynchronously load images to you view :

1)  Asyncimageview https://github.com/nicklockwood/AsyncImageView

2)  SDWebImage https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your image sizes could be large as the code looks fine, usually apps like FB/Insta would use low res renditions and then load in higher res after/when needed.

Most people use an image fetching library such as `SDWebImage` as this will async fetch the images and cache them so you don't have to save them on your model and consume the memory.

https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage